# Repetadly shown the Header image in a Linear layout when using layout adapter in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. I need to show a search result on my page. Linear layout in my page consists of an image which i used as a header.Layout adapter and view holder were used to show the details. The problem is that when i getting the result the header image is shown with every search result. I need to show the image header only once how can i do this.This is my layout and code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/main_layout1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageheader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"

           android:src="@drawable/logo" 
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
  <!--  -->
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:id="@+id/ScrollViewSearch" >

<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/main_layout2"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="10dip">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

     <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp" />

</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewUser1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewUser1"
    android:text="Maradona"      
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

<!-- Artist Name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewUserid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Maradoncssdsdsda"      
    android:textColor="#343434"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewUser1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewUser"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>


   </RelativeLayout>
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="25dp"
        android:layout_y="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text=" Send Message"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:textColor="#028dca"
        android:textSize="12dip" />
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"

        android:layout_x="120dp"
        android:layout_y="3dp" />

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="150dp"
        android:layout_y="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Full Profile "
        android:textColor="#028dca"
        android:textSize="12dip"/>

  </AbsoluteLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

class file is

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ListActivity activity;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private ArrayList<String> names;
private FbUser[] folks;
private int folksNumber = 0;


public LazyAdapter(ListActivity activity, ArrayList<String> names) {
    super();

    this.activity = activity;
    this.names = names;
    this.folks = new FbUser[this.names.size()];
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    new FetchDataTask(this, 0).execute(new Void[]{});
}



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    FbUser cachedUser = folks[position]; // trying to get a user from cache

    View item = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    /**
     * If item has not been created yet, we inflate it and pass its personal
     * ViewHolder as a tag parameter. Otherwise we just get an existing
     * ViewHolder.
     */
    if (item == null) {
        //LinearLayout aa=(LinearLayout)item.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        item = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.quicksearchresult, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textViewUser);
        viewHolder.textView1 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserid);
        viewHolder.textView2 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.textViewUser1);
        viewHolder.spinner = (ProgressBar) item.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        item.setTag(viewHolder);





    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();
    }

    /**
     * If the current user has been fetched we put cached data to the view.
     * Otherwise we clear the view.
     */
    if (cachedUser != null) {

        viewHolder.textView.setText(cachedUser.getName());
        viewHolder.textView1.setText(cachedUser.getUserid());
        viewHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.textView2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), cachedUser
                        .getBitmap()), null, null, null);


    } else {
        viewHolder.textView.setText("");
        viewHolder.spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                null, null, null, null);
        viewHolder.textView1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                null, null, null, null);
    }

    return item;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return names.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


public void cacheUser(FbUser user) {
    folks[folksNumber] = user;
    folksNumber++;
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //reload ListView
}


private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView,textView1,textView2;
    public ImageView image1;
    public LinearLayout lay;
    public ProgressBar spinner;
}
```

}

Comment: Couldn't understand clearly...try if(position==0) set your image;

Answer (score 3):

It seems that for every item in your list your are inflating that entire xml file. You want to split that xml file up into two different files, one that includes the header and a ListView (activity_layout.xml), then another that will be the layout for each individual row (row_layout.xml). Then in your adapter class, for each item, inflate an individual row using the row_layout.xml.

Comment: Can you split the layout and explain how to do this, i am new to android that's why..?

Comment: Great tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html